# Holo theme missing when importing support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, eclipse

When I import the Support Library v7 into my workspace in eclipse, I get this error:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name '@style/ Theme.Holo.Light'.

I have another library project that both link to the appcompat library. The funny thing is that I can build and run my project fine when I remove the styles.xml for values-v14. So I can work without Holo theme but it seems really strange that I lose the styles that should be there?

I'm working in eclipse with latest ADT. I've tried cleaning my project, closing / opening eclipse and the project and re-importing the appcompat into my workspace. Also setting the build target to 19 for both of the linked library projects

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a problem with Eclipse/ADT and I have fixed it now. Basically I had previously removed the values-v14/styles.xml file and then at a later date copied the values-v11/styles.xml back into the values-v14 folder. However it didn't properly recognise that it was now in v14 styles.

The solution was to delete the values-v14/styles.xml and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` instead [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html#Theme_AppCompat)